# Nexus 5 stuck on "flying color dots lollipop" screen after Hard Factory Reset

Tags: boot, nexus-5, bootloader, 5.0-lollipop

I just did a wipe data/factory reset on my Nexus 5. I followed [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHJV_UprpE8).

I'm stuck on the boot screen, which was my problem in the first place, and it's been on the boot screen for 25 minutes.

Should I wait or do something else?

Answer (score 8):

If you have been waiting an excessive amount of time for your phone to boot (eg. leaving it overnight to boot) but it is still at the boot animation, you may be in *bootloop*. This is when the phone fails to boot due to some errors in the `/system` partition. As a preliminary measurement, you should perform a *factory reset* (or wipe `/data`) to see if that helps. If  that does not help, you should reinstall the `/system` partition.

1. First, you have to format your `/system` directory; you will need a custom recovery to do this. I recommend [TWRP (Nexus 5)](http://techerrata.com/browse/twrp2/hammerhead), but regardless of which recovery you choose, you should download the latest version.
2. Power off your Nexus 5, then press and hold Vol-, Vol+ and Power simultaneously. **Don’t release the buttons until *Fastboot Mode* menu appears.** *Excessive force is not necessary and may break your buttons.*
3. Now, you will have to use the adb and fastboot tools. Open a terminal/cmd in your adb/fastboot folder on your PC. If you have the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html), they are usually located in `/path-to-sdk/sdk/platform-tools/`. *Alternatively, you can install the [Minimal ADB and Fastboot](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317790) tool for Windows (or `sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot` for Linux)*.
4. Now plug in your phone to your PC. Making sure that your phone is in *fastboot mode* , type into terminal/cmd: `fastboot devices` to make sure that your phone is properly connected (it should return a serial code to you). This next command will perform a factory reset on your phone, so be wary that **this will wipe all user data from the phone**: `fastboot oem unlock`. After you have issued that command, type `fastboot reboot`. You will be presented with a screen containing an android logo and a progress bar (this may take up to ten minutes to complete). After that, your phone will try to boot up again. Just power it off **after the android logo and progress bar are no longer on your screen**.
5. Now we will use that recovery.img file we downloaded earlier. Reboot your phone into *fastboot mode* with Vol-, Vol+, and power, as in step 2. Make sure it is connected with `fastboot devices`. In the same terminal/cmd, type `fastboot flash recovery /downloads/recovery.img`, replacing `/downloads/recovery.img` with the full path to your downloaded recovery.
6. After that is done, on the phone, use the volume buttons to scroll onto "**Restart Bootloader**" and hit power to select it. After the bootloader reloads, use the volume buttons to scroll onto **"Recovery Mode**" and power to select it. You should then be greeted with your newly installed custom recovery.
7. These are instructions for TWRP: Once your recovery is running, tap **Wipe > Advanced Wipe** and tick only system, data, cache, and dalvik cache. Now swipe to **Wipe**. *This will wipe all system and user data from the device; data on external sd cards will be preserved if you only selected those 4 partitions.*
8. Now, you will download a fresh system image. If you want to stick with a stock ROM, [here is one from XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/development/rom-android-4-4-3-ktu84m-rooted-busybox-t2557523) (This version is rooted). There are many custom ROMs available on the [XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5). Download the ROM image.
9. Now, back in TWRP, make sure you are on the home screen (there should be a home button on the bottom) and go to **Advanced > ADB Sideload** then swipe to activate the mode. Type `adb devices` to make sure your device is properly connected, then type `adb sideload /downloads/ROM.zip`, replacing `/downloads/ROM.zip` with the full path to the ROM (.zip file) you just downloaded. This may take up to ten minutes to complete.
10. After that is done, just reboot! From the TWRP home screen, go to **Reboot > System** and it should boot correctly. *Keep in mind that the first boot may take up to an hour to complete, so **keep it connected to a power source!***

Comment: What happens when in Step 4, I never see the progress bar? It just shows the android logo animation indefinitely.

Comment: Have the same problem as @JPL, don't see any progress bar in step 4, if I try to flash TWRP without reboot after oem unlock it seems to succeed but fails to load (After recovery loading screen phone eventually resets to go into bootloop again)

Answer (score 7):

Posting this not so much for the asker, since it was asked ten hours ago, but for others who find this question:

Lollipop's first boot can take a long time. On my Nexus 4, after the OTA update from 4.4.4, it took about half an hour. At least 10 minutes of this was spent in the "flying colours" boot screen. I'd make sure it has power, and leave it for at least 30-60 minutes before getting too worried.

Comment: Waited for 2h and still stuck so not sure it will work at all.

Comment: I decided to keep waiting after I read this post. It eventually got to the welcome screen. Probably only took about 15min, but it seemed like an eternity.

Comment: Took me a good 20 mins.. but it finally got there.. phew.

Comment: This should definitely be the first line of offense before trying the more complicated answer involving  TWRP